# Tracking small moving targets in Vuforia

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to track up to two small moving objects the size of a small toy car (about 7x4x4 cm / 3x2x2”)  from a 75cm / 2ft distance. I’m aware that the distance/size ratio is about 20, which is off by factor compared to the by Vuforia recommended ratio.

I've tried frame markers and while frame markers are super fast close up, they don't work well at a distance. I'm hesitant to use expensive object recognition on moving targets. I’ve tried black and white QR codes and AR markers as image targets but Vuforia seems to have trouble recognizing them, even though the QR code has a five star rating.

I’m considering two more options:

1) an optimized 4x4cm color image target

2) add LEDs to the objects and track the LEDs, for example like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoL0bIGk_uE

My questions:

1) Are there specific tips for creating small image targets (I have read the generic image target optimizations tips assume not all those tips apply to small targets)

2) Is there an easy way to track LEDs in Vuforia?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the object recognition is your best chance to get this working. I never read anything about LED recognition in Vuforia. For my experience I think small image targets work besser as coloured ones instead of black and white. You could create them with this tool http://www.brosvision.com/ar-marker-generator/ They worked pretty good for me compares to QR-Codes.